# Regex combine lines

Tags: regex, combinations, pcre

Given the following string

```
45op0
tr ico
JJB Be
tyuh
113-4997
202076
acure
sala mandra
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
45op0;113-4997
tr ico;202076
JJB Be;acure
tyuh;sala mandra
```

Basically combine the 4 lines at the bottom with the 4 at the top, in their original order, in a `;` separated list.

This is the regex I have so far:

```
^((?:[^\r*\n]*[\r*\n]){4})([\s\S]*)
```

subtituted by:

```
$1;$2
```

as shown in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2G64a0/1)

As you can see, this does not give the expacted result.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This would almost certainly be far easier to do in your application layer.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression

```
^(.+)\r?\n(?=(?:.*\r?\n){3}(.+))
```

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hx2fjD/2/)

For the example given there are four matches: `45op0`, `tr ico`, `JJB Be` and `tyuh`. Each match has two capture groups. The first capture group contains the match itself. For the first match (`45op0`), capture group 2 contains contains `113-4997`, which is captured in the positive lookahead. The contents of the two capture group can then be joined, separated by a semicolon, to return `45op0;113-4997`

Similarly, for the second match capture group 2 contains `202076`, and so on.

When the line `113-4997` is reached, it is saved in cap grp 1, the next three lines are consumed and then the regex fails because there is no non-empty line following. For the next lines the regex fails because it is unable to skip three lines.

The PCRE regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^(.+)          match a line with 1+ chars, excl. line terminators,
               in cap grp 1 
\r?\n          match the newline and possible carriage return
(?=            begin a positive lookahead
  (?:.*\r?\n)  match an entire line in a non-cap group          
  {3}          execute the non-cap group 3 times (skip 3 lines)
  (.+)         match a line with 1+ chars, excl. line terminators,
               in cap grp 2
)              end positive lookahead
```

Comment: That's similar to what I came up with, but I couldn't find anyway to entirely get rid of the last 4 lines (best I could do was reduce them to a `;`). That's why I suggested it should be done in the application layer.

Comment: @Nick, code is certainly required to do anything with regex matches, but the OP has not given us the language being used so this is as far as I can go. If the variables `str` and `r` hold the string and my regex, respectively, in Ruby one may write `str.gsub(r).map { |_,a| m = Regexp.last_match; "%s;%s" % [m[1],m[2]] }  
 #=> ["45op0;113-4997", "tr ico;202076", "JJB Be;acure", "tyuh;sala mandra"]`. I expect it would be something similar in any other general-purpose language. There's no need to do anything with the last 4 lines.

Comment: Thanks so much @CarySwoveland I change the substitution to `$1;$2\r` and now there is exactly what I was asking for in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/golJCy/1) + the addttional half at the bottom. I can easily delete those lines in the application. For completion, could something be added to the expression as to not return those lines?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to "remove" the last four lines. I view it as reading all 8 lines and returning 4 (with your slight change), or viewed differently, replacing all 8 lines with the 4 that are produced. By the way, in the Ruby code I mentioned above I guess I should have written, `result = ''; str.gsub(r).each {  m = Regexp.last_match; result << "%s;%s\n" % [m[1],m[2]] } #=> "45op0;113-4997\ntr ico;202076\nJJB Be;acure\ntyuh;sala mandra\n"`. I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: I have to remove the last 4 lines, because the desired result is already in the first 4. I am not using Ruby or any language like that. Regex is many orders of magnitude faster than the application I am using, so the more that can be done with Regex the better. Even taking a result and apply another regex to it, is beneficial. What you have provided is more than good enough. Thanks again.